# Graphics Card and XNA 4.0

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xna-3.0

I create a new project in xna 4.0 for windows. I put it on both Reach and HiDef profile settings in properties. When debugging I get the following error:

No suitable graphics card found. Could not find a Direct3D device that supports the XNA Framework HiDef profile.

I made sure to select the 'Reach' profile, I still get this error.

1. Graphics card is an intel GM45. It states support of DX10 on their website.
2. Intel Core 2 Duo 2.2Ghz
3. Windows 7 Professional
4. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
5. 3GB RAM

So whats wrong with what I'm doing? Thanks.

PS. If I cant run XNA 4.0 games, Can I create a 3.0 project with xna 4.0?

Comment: Are you running on Windows XP?

Comment: This seems like a problem for superuser.com, not stackoverflow.com.  However, Intel video cards are very underpowered.  Many of them emulate some of the more intensive (expensive) features with software (in the drivers), or are simply not fast enough for the job.  In general, you have to get a very expensive laptop to get any benefit from current-gen gaming or graphics software, or a normally priced desktop.  The reason this is a comment is I don't know the exact requirement to support the XNA high def profile.

Comment: I have all requirements, Its a problem with how I created my xna project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Edit***: My mistake - I see you're having trouble actually making your game even *use* Reach profile. You should take a look at this article that describes [how to select the Reach profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127182039/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/19/selecting-reach-vs-hidef.aspx).

Also - there were some profile limitations in older versions of XNA 4.0 - I cannot remember the details now, but are you using the latest version of XNA 4.0?

I'll leave my old answer here because there's some other useful info in it:

---

This is probably a better question for the XNA fourm (and I see you've [asked it there](https://web.archive.org/web/20100820053617/http://forums.xna.com:80/forums/p/58913/361498.aspx) anyway).

I don't know what the specs of the Intel GM45 are, but I *can* link you to the [precice requirements of the Reach and HiDef profiles](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310004334/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx), so you can try and compare them.

And to answer your final question: You cannot create an XNA 3.1 project with XNA 4.0. XNA is not upwards or downwards compatable. What you **can** do is install versions side-by-side (both the runtime and Game Studio). So simply grab Visual C# 2008 Express and XNA 3.1 and use those.

Answer (score 11):

change the property for Game profile in your project.

Right Click over the project > Properties > XNA Game Studio > Game Profile:

Change the radio buttons from "Use HiDef..." to "Use Reach..."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and it ended up being because my video card didn't have enough embedded RAM for Windows 7 and an XNA 4.0 project to run. Things ran fine in Windows XP, but failed in Windows 7.